# Dropdown select option width changed on inspect or zoom how to?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Little form on page with dropdown select option when I click dropdown on inspected device width 50% zoomed display like below how to full width ?

```css
select {
      -webkit-appearance: none !important;
    -moz-appearance: none !important;
    background-color: transparent;
    height: 45px;
 
    background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAB4AAAAUCAMAAACtdX32AAAAdVBMVEUAAAD///8AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAhMdQaAAAAJ3RSTlMAAAECAwQGBwsOFBwkJTg5RUZ4eYCHkJefpaytrsXGy8zW3+Do8vNn0bsyAAAAYElEQVR42tXROwJDQAAA0Ymw1p9kiT+L5P5HVEi3qJn2lcPjtIuzUIJ/rhIGy762N3XaThqMN1ZPALsZPEzG1x8LrFL77DHBnEMxBewz0fJ6LyFHTPL7xhwzWYrJ9z22AqmQBV757MHfAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC);
    background-position: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    border-radius: 0; 
}
```

```html
<span class="text-danger">*</span>  Trading Platform</label>
      <select  class="form-control">
        <option>Select a trading platform</option> <option>UTrade</option>
        <option>MT4</option>
      </select>
```

Comment: It's a custom select it seems, so without the code of that select we can't help

Comment: Hi @Lk77 Sorry it's my first question I just updated code please check if you can help me.

Comment: which browser do you use ? for me that works fine

Comment: I just inspect it in Google Chrome and zoom 50% its display like previous

Comment: then you have more css code than what you showed, because it works fine, try to see with the dev tools where the style come from

Comment: Yes, I am trying more way, thank you for your help !